# check at least one checkbox validation in jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, checkbox

I have some checkboxes, something like this:

```
<form name="submit-form" name="submit-form">
<label>property1</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="property1"><br>
<label>property2</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="property2"><br>
<label>property3</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="property3"><br>
<label>property4</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="property4"><br>
<label>property5</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="property5"><br>
<label>property6</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="property6"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

I would like to validate that atleast one checkbox at a time. plz help me. thanks in advance

Comment: place actual html please

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$("#YourbuttonId").click(function(){
    if($('#YourTableId').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == 0)
    {
        alert('Please select atleast one checkbox');
    }
});
```

**Update:**

i saw your code and seems like you are using jquery validation plugin in that case this post will help you

and try giving your checkbox same name which exist in a group

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/check-that-at-least-1-checkbox-is-checked-using-jquery-validate-plugin

Comment: it works only when I refresh the page, not on submit the form.

Comment: it not works. there are some other validations, all are working except this

Comment: http://royalgroupinternational.com/add_enquiry/ check the source code of this for html.

Comment: for which checkbox group you want this

Comment: thanks, you help me a lot... that link helped me to solve the problem and all credit goes to you. thanks once again...

Answer (score 2):

I'd wrap them all in a container with a div just for easier selecting, and then you can use:

```
if($('#wrapperID input:checked').length > 0) {
    'at least one is checked
}
```

Comment: OK. Then put the ID on the table.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    if($("input:checked").length == 0){
    alert('please checked atleast one');
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RGUTv/  **OR** your specific case demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/J98Ua/

My old response here: [validation for at least one checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512448/validation-for-at-least-one-checkbox/11512622#11512622)

hope rest fits the needs! `:)`

**code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my-form').submit(function() {
        amIChecked = false;
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
            if (this.checked) {
                amIChecked = true;
            }
        });
        if (amIChecked) {
            alert('atleast one box is checked');
        }
        else {
            alert('please check one checkbox!');
        }
        return false;
    });
});​
```

Comment: it not works. I know u solve many of the problems of checkbox validation before this but it not works and I don't want it in alert...

Comment: @Ravneet'Abid' Cool man, lol can you make a demo of your problem of flick the JQ code please? Lemme know what part actually doesn't work.