# jQuery Validation Plugin - make checkbox group required based on dropdown response

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate, conditional-statements

I'm using the jQuery Validation plugin with an HTML form for the first time. I'm used to using plain old javascript for this, but I totally love this plugin! Anyway, I'm stuck on trying to do some conditional validating.

The scenario: I have a two-part question in a form. The first part is a Yes/No dropdown (required). The second part is a group of checkboxes, which you must check at least one of them if you selected "Yes" in the previous dropdown.

```
<div>
<p><span class="bold large-font">8.</span> Some question to answer Yes or No to...</p>
<div class="margin-left-fifty">
    <select id="Q8" class="Q8" name="Q8">
        <option value="" selected></option>
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="margin-left-fifty">
    <p><span class="underline italic">If Yes,</span> indicate which areas...</p>
</div>
<div class="margin-left-eighty">
    <input id="Q8yesA" class="Q8yes" name="Q8yesA" type="checkbox" value="Yes" />                    
    <label for="Q8yesA"><span class="small-font">a.</span> Option A</label>
    <br />
    <input id="Q8yesB" class="Q8yes" name="Q8yesB" type="checkbox" value="Yes" />                                            
    <label for="Q8yesB"><span class="small-font">b.</span> Option B</label>
    <br />
    <input id="Q8yesC" class="Q8yes" name="Q8yesC" type="checkbox" value="Yes" />                                            
    <label for="Q8yesC"><span class="small-font">c.</span> Option C</label>
    <br />
    <input id="Q8yesD" class="Q8yes" name="Q8yesD" type="checkbox" value="Yes" />                        
    <label for="Q8yesD"><span class="small-font">d.</span> Other</label>
    <input name="Q8yesDlist" type="text" maxlength="255" size="50" value="" placeholder="Please list..." />                    
</div>
```

Note that is part of a rather large survey, so to make it easier and quicker to collate, I made each response an individual, rather than using an array.

I believe the code I'm using to validate the checkboxes is from here:
[validation for at least one checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512448/validation-for-at-least-one-checkbox)

So right now, my function looks like this:

```
$(function(){

$.validator.addMethod('Q8yes', function (value) {
return $('.Q8yes:checked').size() > 0; }, 'Please check at least one box for Question 8.');

var checkboxes8 = $('.Q8yes');
var checkbox_names8 = $.map(checkboxes8, function(e,i) { return $(e).attr("name")}).join(" ");              

$('#survey').validate({
groups: {
    checks8: checkbox_names8
},
rules: {
  Q8: "required",
},
messages: {
  Q8: "Please answer Question 8.",                              
},
errorContainer: $('#errorContainer'),
errorLabelContainer: $('#errorContainer ul'),
wrapper: 'li'
});
});
```

I've been trying to wrap the addMethod in an If statement, but couldn't quite figure it out. I'm not even sure if that's the right idea.

You're help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, and you're on track for one of them.  I'm going to suggest a different way though.  First off, it makes sense to reorganize your checkboxes to all have the same `name` attribute but different `value` attributes.  That will make them behave better within jQuery Validate.  This is what you have now:

```
<input id="Q8yesA" class="Q8yes" name="Q8yesA" type="checkbox" value="Yes" />
```

Change that to:

```
<input id="Q8yesA" class="Q8yes" name="Q8yes" type="checkbox" value="Q8yesA" />
```

Now, for the actual jQuery Validate code.  You probably don't need groups if you do this the way I suggested, instead you can just have `rules` that look like this:

```
rules: {
    Q8: "required",
    Q8yes: {
        required: '#Q8 option[value="Yes"]:selected'
    },
    Q8yesDlist: {
        required: '#Q8yesD:checked'
    }
 }
```

I've used the `dependency-expression` version of the [required](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required#dependency-expression) rule.

Here's what it looks like in action:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/fccPf/

Comment: After reading many, many posts, I figured a change like that would have to occur. I love the dependency-expression, very useful! My hangup is on the backend with my mySQL table. Like I said, the reason I had different names was due it being a large survey, and when I download the CSV from mySQL for the analysts, I was trying to avoid them having to do any 'text-to-column' operations. I know this may be out of your scope, but would you have a suggestion about that, in terms of passing the values to mySQL, for renaming these all the same? It's ok if you don't...just curious. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you need, but chances are you could use the `submitHandler` to re-jig the form data before submitting it via an AJAX request?