# validation at least one checkbox (multiple group of checkboxes)

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I know this've been answered in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512448/validation-for-at-least-one-checkbox) 
But my html looks like below :

```
<div >
    <label> <input type="checkbox" name="service_area[]" value="colorado">colorado</label>
    <label> <input type="checkbox" name="service_area[]" value="michigan">michigan</label>
</div>

<div >
    <label> <input type="checkbox" name="fav[]" value="skiing">skiing</label>
    <label> <input type="checkbox" name="fav[]" value="volley">volley</label>
</div>
```

Objectives :

- name must have array, in here : service_area[]
- must show only one error message

How to achieve this ? 
Each time I use jvalidate with '[]' name, it seems that it only reflects to the first element, not all elements.

### UPDATE:

I forget to mention that I have more than one group of checkboxes that needed to be checked. 
Updated above html. 
So, rynhe answer inspired me a bit :

```
$.validator.addMethod(
  "atleastone",
  function(value, element, params) {
    return $('[name="' + element.name +'"]:checked').size() > 0;
  },
  'at least one');

  rules: {
    'service_area[]': {
      atleastone : true,
    },
    'fav[]': {
      atleastone : true,
    },
```

The most important part is `'service_area[]'`.
Above code **works** fine for me.
Thx ~

Comment: Why you don't use id ?

Comment: Try this selector `$('[name="service_area[]"]')`

Comment: @ArunChandranC, use `id` for what?  The jQuery Validate plugin requires that every input have a `name` attribute regardless of how the rules are assigned.

Comment: HenryH. -  **simply use the `required` rule.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You do not need to add any special methods in this case.**  When every checkbox in one group shares the same `name`, simply **use the `required` rule**.  Since the names contain brackets, `[]`, enclose it with quotes.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            'service_area[]': {
                required: true
            },
            'fav[]': {
                required: true
            }
        }
    });

});
```

- At least one checkbox from `service_area[]` group is required.
- At least one checkbox from `fav[]` group is required.

I used the `errorPlacement` option to move the error message before each grouping but you can adjust as needed.  [See all plugin options](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate).

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/AsuyC/**

Answer (score 0):

As per `Tats_innit` answer which is in [**validation for at least one checkbox**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512448/validation-for-at-least-one-checkbox)

you can change this line

`var checkboxes = $('.require-one');`

to

`var checkboxes = $('input[name="river[]"]');`

as per your html element `var checkboxes = $('input[name="service_area[]"');`

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/RGUTv/226/)

Comment: forgot your closing square brackets, $('input[name="service_area[]"**]**'); . [attribute-equals-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Comment: updated my question. my question should be how to apply this when I have more than one group checkboxes need to be checked. thx anyway. your answer inspired me