# validating the checkbox in jquery with the minimum limit

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How to validate the checkboxes in jquery with the minimum limit of selection. i am using the jquery plugin for form validation that validates the field by passing the field name.

```
jQuery('#myform').validate({

        rules: {
          checkbox_name: {
            required: true
          }


 });
```

now how to apply the minimum selection limit in this criteria?

Comment: possible duplicate of [validation for at least one checkbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512448/validation-for-at-least-one-checkbox)

Comment: If you want help, you have to make it easy for people to help you... show the HTML markup for this form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `required` rule is all that's needed to make at least one checkbox required.

Yours didn't work because you were missing a closing brace within `.valdiate()`...

```
$('#myform').validate({
     rules: {
         checkbox_name: {
             required: true
         }
     } // <- this bracket was missing
 });
```

Simple DEMO that makes one of the checkboxes from the group required...

DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/gh96s/

---

If you want to required that at least X number of checkboxes from the group are selected, use the `minlength` rule.  (you can also use the `maxlength` or `rangelength` rules)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            checkbox_name: {
               required: true,
               minlength: 2  // at least two checkboxes are required
               // maxlength: 4 // less than 5 checkboxes are required
               // rangelength: [2,4] // must select 2, 3, or 4 checkboxes
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/gh96s/2/**